# Python dictionary optimize this script

Tags: python

I have a string like `rdb_master_mongodb` where `rdb_` is fixed and `master` is a database name which can be anything and `mongodb` can be one among `mysql`, `mongodb`, `postgres`, `mssql` or `bdb`. I need to fetch the value for this string from the dictionary which has the value in `myDict[master][mongodb]`. In order to get this I need to split the string `rdb_master_mongodb` and get the values of `master` and `mongodb`. I can't use split because sometimes the string becomes `rdb_master_test_mongodb`. Hence I have to use `endswith` to get the exact key. Howeveer, `endswith` does not work on a list.

I have to get the matching tuple value from a tuple. Right now I do this like:

```
import re 
name = 'rdb_master_mongodb'
s = re.sub('rdb_', "", name)
VALID_DB = ('mysql', 'postgres', 'mongodb', 'mssql', 'bdb')
(a, b, c, d, e) = VALID_DB
if s.endswith(a):
   db = a
if s.endswith(b):
  db = b
if s.endswith(c):
  db = c
if s.endswith(d):
  db = d
if s.endswith(e):
  db = e
db_name = re.sub('_'+db, "", s)
print db_name+" is "+db
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format of `name` is always the same, you can split it into parts first:

```
rdb, temp = name.split('_', 1)
master, db = temp.rsplit('_', 1)
```

then check whether `db` is valid:

```
VALID_DB = ('mysql', 'postgres', 'mongodb', 'mssql', 'bdb')
if db in VALID_DB:
   ...
```

then use these three variables `rdb, master, db` to build needed strings.

Comment: `rdb, master, db = 'rdb_master_test_mongodb'.split('_')` gives `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.

Comment: You should split twice,I think.

Comment: @LevLevitsky - you're right, then we have to split it twice. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
db = name.rsplit('_', 1)[1]
if db not in VALID_DB:
    raise ValueError('Incorrect DB name: %s' % db)
```

Comment: @bubby Glad to help. Consider accepting the answer if it helps (the tick to the left).

Answer (score 0):

So only the end of the word is significant, if I understand you well, in this case I'd try:

```
>>> VALID_DB = ('mysql', 'postgres', 'mongodb', 'mssql', 'bdb')
>>> name = 'rdb_master_mongodb'
>>> db_name = [db for db in VALID_DB if name.endswith(db)][0]
>>> db_name
'mongodb'
>>> name_test = 'rdb_master_test_mongodb'
>>> db_name = [db for db in VALID_DB if name_test.endswith(db)][0]
>>> db_name
'mongodb'
```

Comment: `.endswith` ignores the position of `_` and accepts `"xxx_badmysql".endswith('mysql')` too.